# Woocommerce stripe charge user after buying additional items from upsell

Tags: php, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I have a code that instead of redirecting user to thank you page they're firsty being redirected to upsell page where they can modify existing order by adding additional items. In the initial order they have placed the payment request (charging) also happens but the thing is I need to charge user if they decide to buy additional item from upsell. I don't really know how to do this. They have customer account and payment details are saved in their account.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'set_wc_session_original_order_id');
function set_wc_session_original_order_id( $order ) {
    WC()->session->set('original_order_id', $order->get_id());
}



add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_shop_order_process_redirects');
function custom_shop_order_process_redirects() {
    if ( is_page('upsell-1') && isset($_GET['woocommerce_checkout_place_order']) ) {
        $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');
        $selected_product_id = isset($_GET['selected_product_id']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['selected_product_id']) : '';
        if ( $order_id > 0 && !empty($selected_product_id) ) {
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            $order->add_product(wc_get_product($selected_product_id));
            $order->calculate_totals();
            WC()->session->set('upsell-1-viewed', true);
            wp_redirect('/upsell-2');
            exit;
        }
    } elseif ( is_page('upsell-2') && isset($_GET['woocommerce_checkout_place_order']) ) {
        $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');
        $selected_product_id = isset($_GET['selected_product_id']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['selected_product_id']) : '';
        if ( $order_id > 0 && !empty($selected_product_id) ) {
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            $order->add_product(wc_get_product($selected_product_id));
            $order->calculate_totals();
            WC()->session->set('upsell-2-viewed', true);
            wp_redirect('/upsell-3');
            exit;
        }
    } elseif ( is_page('upsell-3') && isset($_GET['woocommerce_checkout_place_order']) ) {
        $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');
        $selected_product_id = isset($_GET['selected_product_id']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['selected_product_id']) : '';
        if ( $order_id > 0  && !empty($selected_product_id) ) {
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            $order->add_product(wc_get_product($selected_product_id));
            $order->calculate_totals();
            WC()->session->set('upsell-3-viewed', true);
            WC()->session->__unset('original_order_id');
            wp_redirect($order->get_checkout_order_received_url());
            exit;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    if ( is_page('upsell-1') && isset($_GET['upsell_decline_offer']) ) {
        $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');
        if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
            WC()->session->set('upsell-1-viewed', true);
            wp_redirect('/upsell-2');
            exit;
        }
    } elseif(is_page('upsell-2') && isset($_GET['upsell_decline_offer'])){
        $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');        
        if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
            WC()->session->set('upsell-2-viewed', true);
            wp_redirect('/upsell-3');
            exit;
        }
    } elseif(is_page('upsell-3') && isset($_GET['upsell_decline_offer'])){
        $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');        
        if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            WC()->session->set('upsell-3-viewed', true);
            WC()->session->__unset('original_order_id');
            wp_redirect($order->get_checkout_order_received_url());
            exit;   
        }        

    }
    
    
    
    
    
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'check_if_upsell_was_viewed', 20);
function check_if_upsell_was_viewed(){
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        if(WC()->session->__isset('original_order_id')){
            wp_redirect('/upsell-1');
            if(WC()->session->__isset('upsell-1-viewed')){
                wp_redirect('/upsell-2'); 
                exit;
            } elseif(WC()->session->__isset('upsell-2-viewed')){
                wp_redirect('/upsell-3');
                exit;
            } elseif(WC()->session->__isset('upsell-3-viewed')){
              $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');
              wp_redirect($order->get_checkout_order_received_url());
              exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found this function in stripe maybe I can use this one to generate a payment

```
/**
 * Generate the request for the payment.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 * @version 4.5.4
 * @param  WC_Order $order
 * @param  object   $prepared_payment_method Stripe Payment Method or Source.
 * @return array()
 */
public function generate_payment_request( $order, $prepared_payment_method ) {
    $settings                              = get_option( 'woocommerce_stripe_settings', [] );
    $statement_descriptor                  = ! empty( $settings['statement_descriptor'] ) ? str_replace( "'", '', $settings['statement_descriptor'] ) : '';
    $short_statement_descriptor            = ! empty( $settings['short_statement_descriptor'] ) ? str_replace( "'", '', $settings['short_statement_descriptor'] ) : '';
    $is_short_statement_descriptor_enabled = ! empty( $settings['is_short_statement_descriptor_enabled'] ) && 'yes' === $settings['is_short_statement_descriptor_enabled'];
    $capture                               = ! empty( $settings['capture'] ) && 'yes' === $settings['capture'] ? true : false;
    $post_data                             = [];
    $post_data['currency']                 = strtolower( $order->get_currency() );
    $post_data['amount']                   = WC_Stripe_Helper::get_stripe_amount( $order->get_total(), $post_data['currency'] );
    /* translators: 1) blog name 2) order number */
    $post_data['description'] = sprintf( __( '%1$s - Order %2$s', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ), wp_specialchars_decode( get_bloginfo( 'name' ), ENT_QUOTES ), $order->get_order_number() );
    $billing_email            = $order->get_billing_email();
    $billing_first_name       = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $billing_last_name        = $order->get_billing_last_name();

    if ( ! empty( $billing_email ) && apply_filters( 'wc_stripe_send_stripe_receipt', false ) ) {
        $post_data['receipt_email'] = $billing_email;
    }

    switch ( $order->get_payment_method() ) {
        case 'stripe':
            if ( $is_short_statement_descriptor_enabled && ! ( empty( $short_statement_descriptor ) && empty( $statement_descriptor ) ) ) {
                $post_data['statement_descriptor'] = WC_Stripe_Helper::get_dynamic_statement_descriptor( $short_statement_descriptor, $order, $statement_descriptor );
            } elseif ( ! empty( $statement_descriptor ) ) {
                $post_data['statement_descriptor'] = WC_Stripe_Helper::clean_statement_descriptor( $statement_descriptor );
            }

            $post_data['capture'] = $capture ? 'true' : 'false';
            break;
        case 'stripe_sepa':
            if ( ! empty( $statement_descriptor ) ) {
                $post_data['statement_descriptor'] = WC_Stripe_Helper::clean_statement_descriptor( $statement_descriptor );
            }
            // other payment methods error if we try to add a statement descriptor in the request
    }

    if ( method_exists( $order, 'get_shipping_postcode' ) && ! empty( $order->get_shipping_postcode() ) ) {
        $post_data['shipping'] = [
            'name'    => trim( $order->get_shipping_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_shipping_last_name() ),
            'address' => [
                'line1'       => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
                'line2'       => $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
                'city'        => $order->get_shipping_city(),
                'country'     => $order->get_shipping_country(),
                'postal_code' => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
                'state'       => $order->get_shipping_state(),
            ],
        ];
    }

    $post_data['expand[]'] = 'balance_transaction';

    $metadata = [
        __( 'customer_name', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ) => sanitize_text_field( $billing_first_name ) . ' ' . sanitize_text_field( $billing_last_name ),
        __( 'customer_email', 'woocommerce-gateway-stripe' ) => sanitize_email( $billing_email ),
        'order_id' => $order->get_order_number(),
        'site_url' => esc_url( get_site_url() ),
    ];

    if ( $this->has_subscription( $order->get_id() ) ) {
        $metadata += [
            'payment_type' => 'recurring',
        ];
    }

    $post_data['metadata'] = apply_filters( 'wc_stripe_payment_metadata', $metadata, $order, $prepared_payment_method );

    if ( $prepared_payment_method->customer ) {
        $post_data['customer'] = $prepared_payment_method->customer;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $prepared_payment_method->source ) ) {
        $post_data['source'] = $prepared_payment_method->source;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $prepared_payment_method->payment_method ) ) {
        $post_data['payment_method'] = $prepared_payment_method->payment_method;
    }

    /**
     * Filter the return value of the WC_Payment_Gateway_CC::generate_payment_request.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     * @param array $post_data
     * @param WC_Order $order
     * @param object $source
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wc_stripe_generate_payment_request', $post_data, $order, $prepared_payment_method );
}
```

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/cross-sells You will need to code your own using the API and read limitations too. In woo you offer products in cart that can user add if they want and complete the order.